# limit of complex numbers $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\bar{z}^2} {z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\bar{z}^2} {z}$$

How can we calculate this limit

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the polar coordinates to express $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $| { \overline{z}^2 \over z } | = | { z^2 \over z}| = |z|$. Hence $\lim_{z \to 0} { \overline{z}^2 \over z } = \lim_{z \to 0} z = 0$.